# Why codecov is not showing report in comments?

Tags: code-coverage, travis-ci

I'm trying to setup codecov as code coverage tool in a repository. However, it is passing Travis CI test but not showing codecov report. Here is link of travis report - https://travis-ci.org/fossasia/susper.com/builds/213793203 (see under `bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)`). What should I do?

Here is the source code -

package.json

```
 {
   "name": "susper",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "license": "MIT",
   "angular-cli": {},
   "scripts": {
     "start": "ng serve",
     "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
     "test": "ng test",
     "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
     "e2e": "protractor"
   },
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
     "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
     "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
     "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
     "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
     "@ngrx/router-store": "^1.2.5",
     "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
     "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.3",
     "core-js": "^2.4.1",
     "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.6",
     "reselect": "^2.5.4",
     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
     "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
     "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.0",
     "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
     "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
     "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
+    "codecov.io": "^0.1.6",
     "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
     "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
-    "karma": "1.2.0",
+    "karma": "^1.2.0",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
     "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
+    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
     "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
     "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
     "protractor": "4.0.9",
     "ts-node": "1.2.1",
     "tslint": "^4.0.2",
     "typescript": "~2.0.3",
     "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
   }
 }
```

travis.yml

```
sudo: required
 dist: trusty
 language: node_js
 node_js:
 - 6
 before_install:
 - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
 - export DISPLAY=:99.0
 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
+- pip install --user codecov
 before_script:
 - ng build
 script:
 - ng lint
 - >
   docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/app --workdir=/app coala/base coala --version
 after_success:
 - bash ./deploy.sh
+- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
 cache:
     bundler: true
     directories:
     - node_modules
     - .coala-cache
 services: docker
 branches:
    only:
- angular
```

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
 // https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

 module.exports = function (config) {
   config.set({
     basePath: '',
     frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
     plugins: [
       require('karma-jasmine'),
       require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
       require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
-      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
+      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma'),
+      require('karma-coverage')
     ],
     files: [
       { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
     ],
     preprocessors: {
-      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
+      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli'],
+      'src/app/**/*.js': ['coverage']
     },
     mime: {
       'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
     },
     remapIstanbulReporter: {
       reports: {
         html: 'coverage',
         lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
       }
     },
+    coverageReporter: {
+      type : 'lcov',
+      dir : 'coverage/'
+    },
     angularCli: {
       config: './angular-cli.json',
       environment: 'dev'
     },
     reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
               ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
-              : ['progress'],
+              : ['progress', 'coverage'],
     port: 9876,
     colors: true,
     logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
     autoWatch: true,
     browsers: ['Chrome'],
     singleRun: false
   });
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to help out!

**Issue**: No reports are generated. See https://travis-ci.org/fossasia/susper.com/builds/213793203#L390

**Suggestions**

1. You do not need to use the bash uploader and the node uploader in the same project. So you may choose one or the other. Nonetheless, you have configured Codecov properly.
2. Using Docker: http://docs.codecov.io/docs/testing-with-docker

I did not dive deep into your project,  but I suspect the reports are within the docker container and need to be passed through to Travis.

Comment: Thank you, for giving time to my question. : ) I'm confused, then what changes should I do in my code to able to pass codecov reports from docker container?

Comment: Actually, here - https://docs.codecov.io/docs/testing-with-docker you have used `docker run $ci_env ...` and here - https://github.com/codecov/support/wiki/Testing-with-Docker you have written `docker run $ci_env` . Which one should I go for? And where to write them, in travis.yml right? Unable to judge, exactly at which stage?

Comment: I tried adding the lines though, I got this travis report - https://travis-ci.org/fossasia/susper.com/builds/214350499

Comment: Please contact our customer support for more specific help. Thank you! https://codecov.io/support